# Problem to build Uno-Platform Solutions with Visual Studio 2019 Vers.16.2.5

Tags: visual-studio, uno-platform

i'm new in programming on platform.uno I've tried do compile some examples - everythin is fine. But then there was an Update for Visualstuido 2019 to Version 16.2.5.
Now i get a lot of Errors on all projects in the Solution:
Nu1202 - incompatible packages....
I've tried to update the packages, but now the Solution is completely confused.
I've also tried to create a new platform.uno application, but there i got the same problems.

Errors:

```
Error NU1202 Package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-arm. 
Package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 does not support any target frameworks. 
TestForNu1202.UWP C:\Users\km\source\repos\uno\TestForNu1202\TestForNu1202.UWP\TestForNu1202.UWP.csproj 1
```

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: Thank for your question - one example of 178:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-arm. Package System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.2 does not support any target frameworks. TestForNu1202.UWP C:\Users\km\source\repos\uno\TestForNu1202\TestForNu1202.UWP\TestForNu1202.UWP.csproj 


It's an blank unchanged solution, just created with the uno template for creating an appllication.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - after alot of hours and tries i figured it out. On a second PC with the same installation of the compiler it worked - so it has to be a problem of the specific installation of my "problem"-pc.
The solution was to clear the nuget-cache.
In the compiler - tools/options/NuGet Package Manager/General click on "Clear all NuGet Cache(s)". 
[See image of the Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffON.png)
Now you can create again projects with the Uno-Template!
Question is answered an can be closed.
Thanks....